# useLoadScript libraries show error with different values?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-typescript, react-google-maps-api

> const libraries = ['drawing', 'places', 'geometry'];
> const {isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({        googleMapsApiKey: '',
> libraries: libraries    })

Comment: I've tried many solutions, the first was to make libraries as a constant value out of the parent function, but typescript keeps showing the same error which is: 
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '("drawing" | "places" | "geometry" | "localContext" | "visualization")[]'.

Comment: the second solution was using React.useRef() to make a reference to the libraries value, but that also shows the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need a narrower type than `string` because the type of libraries is narrower. It's a union of specific strings.

Try `const libraries: Array<"drawing" | "places" | "geometry"> = ['drawing', 'places', 'geometry']`.